# Magento Call cms page with different Url

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to call single cms page with different url.

I have tried to bty using init observer and cms_page_reneder event by i not getting how to proceed further.
Please help me how i can achieve the same.

Thank you in advance!!!!!

Comment: We'll need to see your code and know more about what your setup is and what you are trying to do before we can help.

Comment: Your question as it's written makes no sense.  Provide an exact example of what you're trying to do with the intended results.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use URL Rewrite Management

Go to Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

Click on Add New URL Rewrite

Select Custom in Create URL Rewrite

Give any ID Path (Example: aboutus)

In Request Path enter another URL of CMS page  (Example: who-we-are)

In Target Path enter actual URL of CMS page    (Example: about-us)

Keep No in Redirect

Click Save

Now navigate to `<your-site-url>/who-we-are`.
You will see about-us page content there

Comment: can we do this without url rewrite Management

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it.